# JBMO 2007/P4 : Prove that if $p$ is a prime number , then the number $A=7p+3^{p}-4$ is not a square .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that if $p$ is a prime number, then the number $A=7p+3^{p}-4$ is not a square .

My solution: If $p=2$, then we have $A=14+9-4=19$, not possible.

So, let $p$ be an odd prime.

By FLT, we have $7p+3^{p}-4\equiv-1 $ (mod $p$).

By using quadratic residue property, we get that -1 can be a quadratic residue of $p$, iff $p\equiv 1$ mod $4$ .

Now, consider $A$ modulo  $4$.

So we get $ A\equiv-2$ (mod $4$).

Hence $A$ cannot be a perfect square.

The problem is that the handout only asks us to use FLT. So can anyone post some hints on how to use only FLT for this question ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that the final argument (mod $4$) is "breaking the rules" of the problem, any more then checking $p=2$ by hand is "breaking the rules".

Comment: @GregMartin true

Comment: And certainly not FLT but "little Fermat".